# Updating data and refreshing excel_file.xlxs with a pivot table using Linux server

Tags: python, excel, linux, sharepoint, pivot-table

How to update excel file data without breaking the pivot tables, when using Linux server?

I have an excel file with existing data  and multiple pivot tables where the data has been added to the data model since they reference multiple tables of data.

I need to update the file's data sheets and refresh the pivot tables without breaking them. I'm using python with Openpyxl library, however I haven't found a solution how to do it yet, or if it's even possible.

Tldr: I need to replace data on excel file and send the file to sharepoint without breaking the existing pivot tables using a server.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example